# Hive:Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new in Hive.
Today I installed the Hive, followed the book and just used CLI create a table. Then I had a problem.

[image]

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Here is the version:
hadoop 2.9.0
HBase 1.4.5
Hive 2.3.3

TIPS:
no MySQL and no hive-site.xml.Just a purity Hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved it.
Thanks to this blog! https://blog.csdn.net/senvil/article/details/48894237 !

In the hive-site.xml, add this:

```
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>false</value>
<description/>
```

Comment: I'm stuck even doing this, it is showing same error

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that I had tried to start the hive-shell before the metastore_db service.

To solve this problem I had to delete (or move) the metastore_db and try the following command:

```
$ rm -rf metastore_db

$ schematool -dbType derby -initSchema

$ hive
```